# How to apply effect to element when it gets attached to dom?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i am using the following jquery bounce effect:

```
(function($){

    /* The plugin extends the jQuery Core with four methods */

    /* Converting an element into a bounce box: */
    $.fn.bounceBox = function(){

        /*
            Applying some CSS rules that center the
            element in the middle of the page and
            move it above the view area of the browser.
        */

        this.css({
            top     : -this.outerHeight(),
            marginLeft  : -this.outerWidth()/2,
            position    : 'fixed',
            left        : '50%'
        });

        return this;
    }

    /* The boxShow method */
    $.fn.bounceBoxShow = function(){

        /* Starting a downward animation */

        this.stop().animate({top:0},{easing:'easeOutBounce'});
        this.data('bounceShown',true);
        return this;
    }

    /* The boxHide method */
    $.fn.bounceBoxHide = function(){

        /* Starting an upward animation */

        this.stop().animate({top:-this.outerHeight()});
        this.data('bounceShown',false);
        return this;
    }

    /* And the boxToggle method */
    $.fn.bounceBoxToggle = function(){

        /*
            Show or hide the bounceBox depending
            on the 'bounceShown' data variable
        */

        if(this.data('bounceShown'))
            this.bounceBoxHide();
        else
            this.bounceBoxShow();

        return this;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

on the following dynamic div which is loaded dynamically:

```
<div id="growl">
    <span id="growl-title" class="growl-title"></span>
    <span id="growl-content" class="growl-content"></span>
</div>
```

currently the effect works as follows: user clicks button then callback javascript is executed after server side completed to show the div with effect as follows:

```
$('#growl').bounceBoxToggle();
```

but i have a case that from server side i show this div based on an attribute (div may gets attached to dom as result of ajax call) as follows:

```
<c:if test="#{showGrowl==true}">
<div id="growl">
        <span id="growl-title" class="growl-title"></span>
        <span id="growl-content" class="growl-content"></span>
</div>
</c:if>
```

, and i want in this case when the div is shown to apply the bounce effect automatically, please advise how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand exactly, but if u need to execute some script along with that div block, u can embed a script block inside the if condition. So whenever your condition is true, the script gets executed.

```
<c:if test="#{showGrowl==true}">
    <div id="growl">
        <span id="growl-title" class="growl-title"></span>
        <span id="growl-content" class="growl-content"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){ // Making an onload function
            $('#growl').bounceBoxToggle();
        })
    </script>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the div is existing:

```
$(function(){ /* onload */
    if($('#growl').length > 0)
      $('#growl').bounceBoxToggle(); 
});
```

Comment: when to make this check ? note that div may gets attached to dom as result of ajax call

Comment: After the AJAX call. Just put it in your callback function. (in this case without the onload-part

Comment: i don't want to make callback each time, i want a generic solution

Comment: you have a callback anyway with your jquery-ajax-function. it is the function body where you proceed your data (make the changes on the DOM with the new content)

Comment: i am using jsf not jquery so sometimes the ajax behavior is done by jsf not jquery

Comment: that does not matter. anywhere in your code, you are changing he dom by adding the new content. just insert the function in that block, but after the changes are done